# Python Tornado gen.engine exception handling

Tags: python, exception, tornado

I am using Tornado 2.4, and I am trying to integrate async call. 
Lets say I need to access to a remote resource through a HTTP call, so I made this function in a `tornado.web.RequestHandler`:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous 
def get(self, *args):
    try:
        self.remote_call()
        return 'OK'
    except Exception, e:
        self.handle_exception(e)

@gen.engine
def remote_call(self):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, 'http://google.com')
    self.process(response)
```

So my problem is, since `remote_call` is yielding a `Task`, it will obviously exit the `remote_call` function and continue the get function. Then when my task is complete, the engine will process the response. 
But if an error happen in the `self.process(response)`, it will not be catch by my except, since this part of the code is not actually called here, but inside the engine where I do have no control.

So my question is, can I have some control on this engine? Can I handle error, can I ask to perform some specific task at the end the function?

I could do this directly in the function like this

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous 
def get(self, *args):
    self.remote_call()
    return 'OK'

@gen.engine
def remote_call(self):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, 'http://google.com')
    try:
        self.process(response)
    except:
        self.handle_exception(e)
```

But I want to make the handle exception generic and not copy pasting this on every of my Handler.

So do I have a way to access to the engine of Tornado? 
Note that I am using Tornado 2.4 but I can migrate to 3.0 if needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle it in 2.4 by decorating your `get` call with `@gen.engine`, wrapping the call to `self.remote_call` in a `gen.Task`, and then `yield`ing from that:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@gen.engine
def get(self, *args):
    try:
        yield gen.Task(self.remote_call)
    except Exception, e:
        self.handle_exception(e)
    self.finish()  # Make sure you call this when `get` is asynchronous.

@gen.engine
def remote_call(self):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, 'http://google.com')
    self.process(response)
```

This will allow you to handle the exception in `get`, though you'll still see a traceback from the exception being raise in `remote_call`.

However, I highly recommend you upgrade. Tornado is now on version 4.0. With 3.0 or later, you can use `gen.coroutine` instead of `gen.engine` and `web.asynchronous`:

```
@gen.coroutine 
def get(self, *args):
    try:
        yield self.remote_call()
    except Exception, e:
        self.handle_exception(e)
    self.finish()

@gen.coroutine
def remote_call(self):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch('http://google.com')
    self.process(response)
```

`coroutine` properly supresses the traceback from any exception thrown in `remote_call`, as well as letting you handle it in `get`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks it works. I had to do this however:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@gen.engine
def get(self, *args):
    try:
        yield gen.Task(lambda cb: self.remote_call())
    except Exception, e:
        self.handle_exception(e)
    self.finish()  # Make sure you call this when `get` is asynchronous.

@gen.engine
def remote_call(self):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, 'http://google.com')
    self.process(response)
```

Comment: You should be able to do `yield gen.Task(self.remote_call)`, rather than using a lambda.